# FFmpeg GL transition command for android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-editing

I run this ffmpeg gl transition command but never get result tell me what is wrong in this command.

```
String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", yourRealPath, "-i", yourRealPath, "-filter_complex",  "-gltransition=duration=4:offset=1.5:source=crosswarp", filePath};
```

Comment: Refer to the ffmpeg log.

Comment: have you successfully compiled the gltransition into android? It won't recognise the filter if you haven't